# Hadoop Pig get subdirectory names from load glob and use it in store

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have this directory structure:

```
/topLevel
   |
    -A
   |
    -B
   |
    ...
```

The names to the directories (A, B, etc.. are not static.  They could change over time).

I understand I can use glob in the load function to load all files under topLevel:

```
load ('/topLevel/*')
```

I have a requirement to use the same sub-directory name under topLevel to store results with.  For the above, I would like to store into:

```
/results
   |
    -A_results
   |
    -B_results
   |
    ...
```

This is not possible, but I would like to do this:

```
store ('/results/*_results')
```

To match the load glob...

Under Pig, how can I get the names of the sub-directories in the load glob and use it in store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Once you load all of the data inside `topLevel` into your Pig alias, all memory of the original filenames is lost.  You have a single alias in Pig, so your output is going to be in a single directory.

If you want to do this, I would recommend using parameter substitution and then using a Bash script to run your Pig script multiple times, once for each input directory.  Something like:

```
for dir in topLevel/*
do
    pig -p input=$dir -p output=results/${dir#topLevel/} myScript.pig
done
```

where the contents of `myScript.pig` are

```
A = LOAD '$input';
...
STORE X INTO '$output';
```